# Add new window to OpeningFcn of MATLAB GUI goes to back of main window when running

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I have a `Main_window` in MATLAB guide. I want open a `New_window` when I run `Main_window`, So I add this code in `OpeningFcn` of `Main_window` :

```
New_window();
```

When I run  `Main_window`, `New_window` goes to back of `Main_window`. I want it in front of `Main_window` after running.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are calling New_window before Main_window has finished executing. 
Ideas:

1. You could simply call Main from new instead. I'm guessing that you already tried this and it doesn't work for your application
2. If you want the user to do something with new_window, then proceed to main_window, you could enable uiwait in the new_window opening fcn to keep it in focus until the user closes it.
3. Create a script that contains two lines

   ```
   Main_window;
   New_window;
   ```

Running that script will start both programs in sequence, and New_window will be on top.

1. Ultimately, if you want to maximize control, you should write your own gui instead of using GUIDE.